# Zend_Form filters rewrite or route - I want a readable URL

Tags: zend-framework, zend-form

I have a form created with Zend_Form and I would like to setup a Route for the submission, so that instead of the user NOT seeing his URL change OR seeing the URL change to a complicated GET string, it will change to reflect the filters.

BAD:
/products

BAD:
/products?color=white&size=large

GOOD:
/products/white/large

GOOD:
/products/color/white/size/large

Is there any way to accomplish this?

Comment: Please note that `/products/color/white/size/large` vs. `/products/size/large/color/white/` will make google furious as it's duplicate content (in contrary to params that **DO NOT** do that)

Answer (score 0):

Not directly via Zend_Form, because at the end Zend_Form draws a HTML Form, and the browser sends it encoded in a URL form.

What you need to do is catch the submit event via Javascript and manually create the URL you want and use window.location to transfer the form.

Comment: Don't forget to fail over to "bad" mode if javascript is disabled in the user's browser.

Comment: In that case it will get submitted as url encoded params, and Zend can work ecually fine with those.